# Applying rules from lookup table

Tags: r

I've got two data frames in R that I've generated from some other stuff I've done.

One is a wide table and contains several numerics. lets call them x1 and x2. These variables can take on values from -999 to 999.

The other data frame is a long table and contains columns for var, min, max, and group. These are essentially a set of if-than rules.  Here's an example:

```
# look up table example
var <- c('x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2')
min <- c(-999, 5, 70, -999, 20)
max <- c(5, 70, 999, 20, 999)
group <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
lkup<- data.frame(var, min, max, group)
```

The data in the table can be read as a set of if-than statements. For instance, The first row of this table c('x1', -999, 5, 1) means that any value in x1 between -999 and 5 should be mapped to 1 in a new variable we'll call y1. All the rows in the table can be interpreted in a similar manner.

y1 should get all the mappings from x1. so it should end up with as many unique values as there are rules for x1.

What I want to be able to do is create a new data frame based on the data in df and the rules in the lookup table.

so for instance, if I have the lookup table above and the data here:

```
# data
x1 <- c(1, 2, 50, 70 , 100)
x2 <- c(2, 3, 4, 50, 60)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
```

I should end up with a table that looks like this:

```
# Desired result
y1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
y2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
result <- data.frame(y1, y2)
```

I thought this was a brilliant solution to a problem I have, but actually getting it done is proving challenging. Any guidance anyone can give me would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
result <- merge(lkup, gather(df, var, value), by = "var") %>%                  
             filter(value > min & value <= max) %>% 
             select(var, group) %>%                  
             group_by(var) %>% mutate(id = seq_len(n())) %>%  
             spread(var, group) %>% select(-id) 

> result
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

     x1    x2
  (dbl) (dbl)
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     2     1
4     2     2
5     3     2
```

To take the order of the original data set into account, you can add an *id* variable to your data making each record unique and traceable:

```
df
  id  x1 x2
1  1   1  2
2  2   2  3
3  3  50  4
4  4  70 50
5  5 100 60
merge(lkup, gather(df, var, value, -id), by = "var") %>% 
     filter(value > min & value <= max) %>% 
     select(id, var, group) %>% spread(var, group)

  id x1 x2
1  1  1  1
2  2  1  1
3  3  2  1
4  4  2  2
5  5  3  2
```

Comment: This works for the data given, but if the order of the data in df isn't ordered (i.e. doesn't look like its been sorted) the result is incorrect.

Comment: If you mean the correspondence between the original data and result, I think the best way is to make an id variable in your original data, which will be kept until the result. Otherwise, you might need to provide an example to show what you mean?